# Android AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android

When I type `a` on EditText, I want to let `add`、`acer`、...show in the drop down menu. I know it can complete with **AutoCompleteTextView**. But I want it also show `bat`、`cat`..., the string `a` is in a word, not in the front.

Comment: have you try some thing? If yes please post your code here...

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://android.foxykeep.com/tag/autocompletetextview) is the same thing for what you are looking for..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to implement your own [Filter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html) class. You then have to implement a ListAdapter (that wraps your list of strings) which also implements the [Filterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) interface; this subclass should return your custom Filter when getFilter is called. You pass your custom ListAdapter/Filterable into an AutoCompleteTextView via the setAdapter() method. (An easy way to do all this is to subclass Android's ArrayAdapter.)

Here's the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) for the ArrayAdapter. Find the definition of the ArrayFilter (at the bottom) and modify it to your needs. The following code is the ArrayFilter with a modification you might be looking for. You'll have to study the effects of `mLock`, `mObjects`, and `mOriginalValues` before applying to your own Adapter subclass.

```
private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (mOriginalValues == null) {
            synchronized (mLock) {
                mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<T>(mObjects);
            }
        }

        if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
            ArrayList<T> list;
            synchronized (mLock) {
                list = new ArrayList<T>(mOriginalValues);
            }
            results.values = list;
            results.count = list.size();
        } else {
            String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

            ArrayList<T> values;
            synchronized (mLock) {
                values = new ArrayList<T>(mOriginalValues);
            }

            final int count = values.size();
            final ArrayList<T> newValues = new ArrayList<T>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                final T value = values.get(i);
                final String valueText = value.toString().toLowerCase();

                if (valueText.contains(prefixString)) {
                    newValues.add(value);
                }
            }

            results.values = newValues;
            results.count = newValues.size();
        }

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        mObjects = (List<T>) results.values;
        if (results.count > 0) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```